# Sencha ajax call to php file

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, extjs

I'm both a sencha and ajax newbie. I'm trying to return some data from a php file that connects to a mysql server. I'm triggering an ajax request when I press a button.

Here is my sencha code for when the button is pressed........

```
    onShow: function(){

        setInterval(function(){
            console.log("Server pinged");
            myRequest = Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'http://localhost/getpoi.php',
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                poiid: '3'
            },
            callback: function(response) {
                console.log(response.responseText);
            }
        });

        },5000);
     },
```

My getpoi php file code is as follows.......

```
    <?php
    $poiid = $_GET["poiid"];
    $lat;
    $long;
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("murmuration_db", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM POI WHERE id=$poiid");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        $lat = $row['anchor_geolocation_lat'];
        $long = $row['anchor_geolocation_lon'];
      }

    $response = $lat. ' '. $long;
    echo $response;
    return $response;
    mysql_close($con);

    ?>
```

The php file is working because if I change set poiid to 3 in the file itself and open it in the browser, I get the position. But if I call it within the sencha app through the button the console is logging 'server pinged' correctly but is logging 'undefined' instead of the co-ordinates. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance
A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it look like you ajax is not sending the request right. 
Try this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    console.log("Server pinged");
    myRequest = Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://localhost/getpoi.php?poiid=3',
    method: 'GET',
    callback: function(response) {
        console.log(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

to be sure that is loading press F12, go to Network and look the requests. ;)
(Firebug or Inspect Element on Chrome)

Comment: Thanks Éder for your response, I tried your code which makes sense to me and unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. In inspect element in network its showing the get methods for the getpoi.php file alright. It seems to be the return part is not working as even if i set the poiid to 3 in the php file its not returning a value to the sencha app, but returning a value if I open the php file in the browser. I'm stumped

Comment: Not yet I'm afraid. I stripped the php file down to return just a string and simplified the request to call the php file but the console still logs undefined. If i change console.log(response.responseText); to console.log(response); the console logs Object {url: "http://localhost/getpoi.php", method: "GET"} instead of undefined! Not sure what to do!

Comment: Finally got it sorted. It worked when I replaced 'callback: function(response)' with 'success: function(response)'. Why I do not know as the sencha documentation informs me that both should work, but hey at least its working. Thanks for your help again.